# jMeter Soap test with multiple requests

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to test a SOAP function through iMeter Soap/XML-RPC Data. The logic is simple, I am passing a user id and want to get the user profile back. I want to test 100 users, user id from 1 to 100. And I want to create 50 threads, each thread run through these 100 ids for 2 hours. My question is how can I make jMeter to call all these 100 user request. The request XML is something like this. Should I just create 100 of these xml request with id from 1 to 100?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://server.smartleads.alliancetech.com" xmlns:data="http://data.post.server.smartleads.alliancetech.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <ser:getRegistration>
        <ser:aaGetRegReqObj>
           <data:action>0</data:action>
           <data:version xsi:nil="true"/>
           <data:debug>true</data:debug>
           <data:id>55</data:id>
        </ser:aaGetRegReqObj>
     </ser:getRegistration>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake in my question, the user is is actually a random number + char combo, it's not just from 1 to 100. I am so sorry for my mistake. In this case, what should I do then? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to get your goal. Some of them:

1. Use [__counter()](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) function
2. Use config emelment - [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter)

For example, if you'll use counter, configure it like this:
[image: counterExample]

Then, use specified reference name in your request:

```
<ser:aaGetRegReqObj>
           <data:action>0</data:action>
           <data:version xsi:nil="true"/>
           <data:debug>true</data:debug>
           <data:id>${userId}</data:id>
        </ser:aaGetRegReqObj>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am sorry I made a mistake in my question, the user is is actually a random number + char combo, it's not just from 1 to 100. I am so sorry for my mistake. In this case, what should I do then? Thanks!

Comment: You could use __random() function - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random

Comment: Or __RandomString() function - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop from 1 to 100 with SOAP/XML sampler:

Loops:
http://2min2code.com/articles/jmeter_intro/loop_controller

SOAP / XML:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request

It looks like you're just getting started with JMeter, here is a JMeter getting started video tutorial:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am sorry I made a mistake in my question, the user is is actually a random number + char combo, it's not just from 1 to 100. I am so sorry for my mistake. In this case, what should I do then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I will use CSV Data Set Config in this case. Thanks all!